# Image OpacityMask not working

Tags: wpf

have I done something wrong here?

```
<Image Source="image.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Name="BGImage">
    <Image.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg" />
    </Image.OpacityMask>
    <Image.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="10" />
    </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

I'm simply using this test image, but the ImageBrush does not work at all... shouldn't either the black/white be invisible? (forgot which one). 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the image to make sure it is selected, and then click Gradient
Brush for the selected OpacityMask property, under Brushes.
Enter 0% in the Alpha field for the left gradient stop. 
Also try to change RGB values too.

Notice how the image on the Artboard changes. Eg;

```
<Image Source="image.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.Effect>
                <BlurEffect KernelType="Box" Radius="10"/>
            </Image.Effect>
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

And to use an Image as an Opacity mask, make an Image with transparent background.

```
    <Image Source="image.jpg">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="mask1.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
        <Image.Effect>
            <BlurEffect KernelType="Box" Radius="2"/>
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>
```

In the image below, left image is the mask applied, beneath it is actual image. Underlying image appears visible wherever masked image is transparent.

[image: Masked image]

Comment: Ah thanks! Usually masks work by using black and white, so thats where I was going wrong!

Comment: You need transparent regions in your mask to see through.